# EWS API: retrieve/update an Exchange appointment

Tags: exchangewebservices

I get the following error message;

Id is malformed.

CD0000008B9511D182D800C04FB1625DBA75FAB1A56555459257CE195FAEBE39

The ID comes from a table where I saved the ID when I created the reminder in the calendar.

CF9 and Exchange 2013:

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment" name="appointment">
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.AppointmentSchema" name="appointmentschema">
<cfset appointment.init( service )>
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertySet" name="propertyset">
<cfset propertyset.init()>
<cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemId" name="thisitemid">
<cfset thisitemid.init("#arguments.ExchangeID#")>
<cfset appointment = appointment.Bind(service, thisitemid) />
<cfscript>
    appointment.setStart(#StartDate#);
    appointment.setEnd(#EndDate#);
    appointment.setSubject("#Arguments.EventName#");
    appointment.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("#Arguments.EventDescription#"));
    appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
</cfscript>
```

Edit:
The following code is what I use today to create an appointment.  However, I haven't figured out how to return the correct "ID" of the appointment so I can save it in case the appointment needs to be deleted or updated.

```
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService" name="service">
    <cfset service.init()>
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion" name="version">
    <cfset service.init(version.Exchange2010)>
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials" name="credentials">
    <cfset credentials.init("#Arguments.EmailAddress#","#Arguments.Pword#")>
    <cfset service.setCredentials(credentials) />
    <cfobject type="Java" class="java.net.URI" name="uri">
    <cfset uri.init("https://south.exch999.serverdata.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx?wsdl")>
    <cfset service.setUrl(uri) />
<cfoutput>
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment" name="appointment">
    <cfset appointment.init( service )>
    <cfobject type="Java" class="microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody" name="MessageBody">
    <cfscript>
    appointment.setStart(#createDateTime(Year(Arguments.EventStartDateTime),       Month(Arguments.EventStartDateTime),Day(Arguments.EventStartDateTime), evaluate(Hour(Arguments.EventStartDateTime)), Minute(Arguments.EventStartDateTime), 0)#);
    appointment.setEnd(#createDateTime(Year(Arguments.EventEndDateTime), Month(Arguments.EventEndDateTime),Day(Arguments.EventEndDateTime), evaluate(Hour(Arguments.EventEndDateTime)), Minute(Arguments.EventEndDateTime), 0)#);
    appointment.setSubject("#Arguments.EventName#");                        appointment.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("#Arguments.EventDescription#"));
    appointment.Save();
    TheEventID = appointment.Id.UniqueId;
    </cfscript>
```

What property should I retrieve to save an ID that can be used to retrieve the appointment later?

Comment: I don't understand how propertydefinition plays in the scheme I setup in the above edited code.

Comment: I'm saving the id as TheEventID = appointment.Id.UniqueId;

But when I try to bind the appointment to update it I get the message:

The specified object was not found in the store.

Comment: Does this happen directly after saving the ID or just with entries that are much older? Are you converting it to hex when it goes into the database and converting it back to Base64 when creating a new ItemId from it? Is the example you posted an actual UniqueId string? If so, it's far too short.

Comment: I had just created the event and checked my DB.  It is a completely different string (much longer) and NOT hex. I tried to modify the event and got the error "not found".

Comment: AAMkADQyMGJhNjE0LTQzZjktNDRiMy05M2M4LWE0NTQxYzA5NWFhMABGAAAAAAD9wuji3kHlSpmR1oSZiZu0BwAnkNsBQ//TS7en1/EP1+R1AAAAAAEOAAAnkNsBQ//TS7en1/EP1+R1AAAuXUjwAAA=

Comment: this is the new id format

Comment: That's a proper ItemId for just about any version of Exchange with EWS support. The only possibility I can think of is that the old Id is the EwsLegacyId. You could try using the ConvertId call to see if you can get a proper ItemId.UniqueId string out of it. As for not being able to find the Item from a newly-created ItemId, I can't say for certain. If Exchange is saying that it can't find it from an Item.Bind from a newly-created one, then I'm not certain what the problem is unless the Item is being moved upon creation or something else that might change the ItemId. Can you debug from CF?

Comment: I can't do a step-by-step debug, but I can add a javascript alert and set a breakpoint on that. I've been using email to dump certain values at a certain point in the code.

Comment: Isn't there a unique ID for each appointment or do I have to loop through appointments to find the one that matches date and time?  from my research it appears that I have to add a unique id property to the appointment then populate it with my own ID value.  To me, this is bad form.

Comment: You can do that, yes. Appointments also have the Global Unique ID, which is generated serverside, but you'd have to retrieve it after creating the Appointment. You'd have to create your own extended property (Don't try using one already in use by Exchange) and give it an ID if you wanted to go that route. As long as your code can ensure it's unique, it shouldn't be an issue, and it can be retrieved with a SearchFilter on your property, no need for looping. This is done pretty often in EWS, from what I understand.

Comment: New wrinkle: When processing appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
I get the following error;
Element ALWAYSOVERWRITE is undefined in CONFLICTRESOLUTIONMODE.

Comment: I think this question should be deleted.  We're not getting anywhere because of my obvious lack of knowledge.  Many thanks to user1017413 for trying.

Answer (score 0):

That looks too short to be an ItemId. I think you may have saved the Global Unique Id or ICalUID from the Appointment instead, or perhaps a different Id that may be converterable via the ConvertId call.

Whoops, sorry, if that's the actual ID you're seeing then it definitely isn't the Global Unique Id. That property is prepended by a specific GUID that does not match what you've shown.

If that's not the full string and the ID you're pulling from the table is longer, then you may only need to convert it to a Base64 String before instantiating the ItemId. Do you have any further info on what exactly "theUID" is or how it is retrieved from the Appointment once it's saved?

If not, then I'm not certain what you're looking at. It doesn't seem to correlate to any specific property in Exchange that I'm aware of. You can try using ConvertId to convert them to other Id types and see if anything comes out (you'll likely have to do Base64 conversions on that hex first). It might be the OWA ID, but I haven't worked with those directly.

If you're looking for an Id, then Appointment.ItemId.UniqueId would work (a new ItemId can be instantiated from the UniqueId string), but be aware that it is NOT an immutable property and can be changed by Exchange if the Appointment is moved to another folder or, supposedly, if a service pack is installed or enough time passes. It should only be used in the short term. You could use the Global Unique Id, but you'd have to explicitly load it as an extended property once the Appointment has been saved. However, the Global Unique Id would require a FindItems operation to retrieve items based on it, and it isn't indexed, so performance might not be so great if you have large folders and frequent searches. You might try a combination of the two: Appointment.Bind with an ItemId and a doublecheck on the Global Unique Id to be sure it's correct, or fall back on it and search if the Appointment could not be found. Alternatively, you could use your own ID instead of the Global Unique Id.

Also, if you're going to use the Global Unique Id, be aware of the Clean Global Unique Id and how they relate to recurrences if you plan on having them.

Comment: I inherited this project and all I can tell you is the ID was created using Exchange 2007 (we are now on 2013) and Coldfusion 9 tag;
<cfexchangecalendar action="create"
    username ="#Arguments.UserName#"
    password="#Arguments.Pword#"
    server="#Application.Exchange.ExchangeHost#"
    event="#sEvent#"
    result="theUID">
And theUID is saved to an SQL table column varchar(max)